# Use Python 2-Style Division in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x, integer-division

I have converted some python 2 code which uses a lot of division into python 3 using `2to3.py`. Now it doesn't work because there are several places where values have become `float`s when they need to be `int`s.

How to fix this please without having to manually check each case and edit when needed? Can I import the python 2 version of division somehow (`from __past__ import division`?!)

Comment: Ah, the joy of porting software.  Not all porting can be automated.

Comment: This is not possible. Use `from __future__ import division` in python2 and fix all cases there.

Comment: You had [**19 years time to fix your code and decided to do it only now**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) :D